# Youtube get video title from id

Tags: php, youtube

I understand this may have been answered somewhere, but after looking and looking through numerous questions/answers and other websites, I'm unable to find a suitable answer.

I'm trying to create a page, which will show some video from Youtube. It will show the image, and title. I've managed to do both of these, although i'm having problems with the title. With the code i'm using, it is awfully slow at loading. I assume because of it loading the actual website just to get the title.

This is what i'm using to get the titles currently.

```
function get_youtube_id($url){
    parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
    return $my_array_of_vars['v']; 
}
function get_youtube_title($video_id){
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id;

$page = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);

$title_div = $doc->getElementById('eow-title');
$title = $title_div->nodeValue;

return $title;

}
```

So, how would the best way to get a youtube title by the id. The code I have does work, but it also makes the page load very very slow.

Thanks

Comment: better use yt's data API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple way to do it using PHP and no library. YouTube already allows you to retrieve video detail information in the JSON format, so all you need is a simple function like this:

```
   function get_youtube_title($ref) {
      $json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $ref . '&format=json'); //get JSON video details
      $details = json_decode($json, true); //parse the JSON into an array
      return $details['title']; //return the video title
    }
```

The function parameter being the video ID. You could also add a second parameter asking for a specific detail and change the function name so you could retrieve any data from the JSON that you would like.

**EDIT:**

If you would like to retrieve any piece of information from the returned video details you could use this function:

```
function get_youtube_details($ref, $detail) {
    if (!isset($GLOBALS['youtube_details'][$ref])) {
        $json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $ref . '&format=json'); //get JSON video details
        $GLOBALS['youtube_details'][$ref] = json_decode($json, true); //parse the JSON into an array
    }

    return $GLOBALS['youtube_details'][$ref][$detail]; //return the requested video detail
}
```

If you request different details about the same video, the returned JSON data is stored in the `$GLOBALS` array to prevent necessary calls to `file_get_contents`.

Also, `allow_url_fopen` will have to be on in your `php.ini` for `file_get_contents` to work, which may be a problem on shared hosts.

Comment: it is a pitty that there is no info about dates

Comment: This code needs the https url, but otherwise works.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Open Graph

[Checkout This Link](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph)

```
<?php
    require_once('OpenGraph.php');

    function get_youtube_title($video_id){
        $url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$video_id;
        $graph = OpenGraph::fetch($url);
        // You can get title from array
        return $graph->title;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! How would I get title from the array?

Comment: you can get `echo $og->title;` with this

Comment: you can refer link that you can understand easily

Comment: Nothing seems to echo out

Comment: i also implement in my project and its working awsome.

Comment: Hm very weird. I don't want to be asking for too much. But would you be able to update the code in your answer with the foreach loop that works? I can't seem to get it to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

It's been 5 years, but my script bellow could be useful.

```html
<?php 

$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBEID");
        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

$document = htmlspecialchars($output);
curl_close($ch);     
        
$line = explode("\n", $document);
$judul = "";
foreach($line as $strline){
      preg_match('/\&lt;title\&gt;(.*?)\&lt;\/title\&gt;/s', $strline, $hasil);
      if (!isset($hasil[0]) || $hasil[0] == "") continue;
            $title =  str_replace(array("&lt;title&gt;", "&lt;/title&gt;"), "", $hasil[0]);
}
        
echo $title;
```